# $location expansion in Bazel

Tags: bazel

I want to add `$(location)` expansion to `rules_scala` for `jvm_flags` attribute where I set the dependency in the `data` attribute but that fails with:
`label '//src/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib:worker' in $(location) expression is not a declared prerequisite of this rule.`
I define a dependency in my target on that label in the `data` attribute like this:

```
scala_specs2_junit_test(
    ...
    data = ["//src/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib:worker"],
    jvm_flags = ["-XX:HeapDumpPath=/some/custom/path", "-Dlocation.expanded=$(location //src/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib:worker)"],
)
```

I saw that when I add `ctx.attr.data` to the `expand_location` call expansion works but I wasn't really sure why this is not a hack. Is `data` indeed a special case?

```
    location_expanded_jvm_flags = []
    for jvm_flag in jvm_flags:
        location_expanded_jvm_flags.append(ctx.expand_location(jvm_flag, ctx.attr.data))
```

Also tried looking in the `java_*` rules sources to see how this works (since `$(location)` expansion there supports the `data` attribute) but couldn't find the relevant place.

Full target:

```
scala_specs2_junit_test(
    name = "Specs2Tests",
    srcs = ["src/main/scala/scala/test/junit/specs2/Specs2Tests.scala"],
    deps = [":JUnitCompileTimeDep"],
    size = "small",
    suffixes = ["Test"],
    data = ["//src/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib:worker"],
    jvm_flags = ["-XX:HeapDumpPath=/some/custom/path", "-Dlocation.expanded=$(location //src/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib:worker)"],
)
```

Comment: Why do you think adding `data` to `expand_location(targets)` is a hack? As I understand the [docs](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/ctx.html#expand_location) that *is* the correct way to do it.

Comment: Why is data different? I don't see anything in the docs saying something specific about the data attribute.

Comment: Different from what? Are there attributes that `expand_location` automatically crawls for targets?

Comment: Doesn't it automatically work for "deps"? Do you know what is the list for the java rules?

Comment: I actually don't know. I would be surprised if "deps" were special-cased. Have you previously used it with `deps` without passing the targets to `expand_location`?

Comment: Just did a small test where I changed `data` to be `deps` in my test (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/master/test/BUILD#L328) and removed the `ctx.attr.data` argument to expand and it works. `runtime_deps` btw, doesn't work out of the box and also requires passing as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for conducting that experiment. Let me answer in a normal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right.

I looked at the source code and you're right: `srcs`, `deps`, and `tools` (if defined on the rule) are added to the set of labels that `expand_locations` understands. `data` is added only if [`LocationExpander`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/7184b6f55a8cb72094a481d056fe89bc7be80c76/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/SkylarkRuleImplementationFunctions.java#L375-L378) is created with `allowDataAttributeEntriesInLabel=true`, which it isn't. That's why you must add it to `expand_locations(targets)`.

Comment: Thanks! The java rules support location expansion on data and runtime deps right?

Comment: I tried something (I think data). Thought you might know. Thanks.