# Idiomatic retrieval of the Bazel execution path

Tags: bazel

I'm working on my first custom Bazel rules. The rules allow the running of [`bats`](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats) command line tests.

I've included the rule definition below verbatim. I'm pretty happy with it so far but there's one part which feels really ugly and non-standard. If the rule user adds a binary dependency to the rule then I make sure that the binary appears on the `PATH` so that it can be tested. At the moment I do this by making a list of the binary paths and then appending them with `$PWD` which is expanded inside the script to the complete execution path. This feels hacky and error prone.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this? I don't believe I can access the execution path in the rule due to it not being created until the execution phase.

Thanks for your help!

```py
BATS_REPOSITORY_BUILD_FILE = """
package(default_visibility = [ "//visibility:public" ])
sh_binary(
  name = "bats",
  srcs = ["libexec/bats"],
  data = [
    "libexec/bats-exec-suite",
    "libexec/bats-exec-test",
    "libexec/bats-format-tap-stream",
    "libexec/bats-preprocess",
  ],
)
"""

def bats_repositories(version="v0.4.0"):
    native.new_git_repository(
      name = "bats",
      remote = "https://github.com/sstephenson/bats",
      tag = version,
      build_file_content = BATS_REPOSITORY_BUILD_FILE
    )

BASH_TEMPLATE = """
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
export TMPDIR="$TEST_TMPDIR"
export PATH="{bats_bins_path}":$PATH
"{bats}" "{test_paths}"
"""

def _dirname(path):
  prefix, _, _ = path.rpartition("/")
  return prefix.rstrip("/")

def _bats_test_impl(ctx):
  runfiles = ctx.runfiles(
      files = ctx.files.srcs,
      collect_data = True,
  )

  tests = [f.short_path for f in ctx.files.srcs]
  path = ["$PWD/" + _dirname(b.short_path) for b in ctx.files.deps]

  sep = ctx.configuration.host_path_separator

  ctx.file_action(
      output = ctx.outputs.executable,
      executable = True,
      content = BASH_TEMPLATE.format(
          bats = ctx.executable._bats.short_path,
          test_paths = " ".join(tests),
          bats_bins_path = sep.join(path),
      ),
  )

  runfiles = runfiles.merge(ctx.attr._bats.default_runfiles)

  return DefaultInfo(
      runfiles = runfiles,
  )

bats_test = rule(
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = True,
        ),
        "deps": attr.label_list(),
        "_bats": attr.label(
            default = Label("@bats//:bats"),
            executable = True,
            cfg = "host",
        ),
    },
    test = True,
    implementation = _bats_test_impl,
)
```

Comment: if my answer helped can you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Your answer is good! I'm waiting for 0.8.0 to be available on my platform so that I can implement the changes myself before I accept. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: Sure thing. Are you waiting for Windows? Other platforms have been released IINM

Comment: I was waiting for this to get merged: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/21106. Should be able to accept this today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be easy to support from Bazel 0.8.0 which will be released in ~2 weeks.
In your skylark implementation you should do `ctx.expand_location(binary)` where `binary` should be something like `$(execpath :some-label)` so you might want to just format the label you got from the user with the `$(execpath)` and bazel will make sure to give you the execution location of that label.

Some relevant resources:
[$location expansion in Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982762/location-expansion-in-bazel)
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2475
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/cff0dc94f6a8e16492adf54c88d0b26abe903d4c

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it and it gives something like: `bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/path/to/binary`. In order to put this into the `$PATH` I think it needs to be an absolute path but I don't know if the entire path is available until the execution phase. Should I have a different methodology? e.g. Pass the relative paths into the testing tool instead of modifying the `PATH`?

Comment: If you can pass the relative paths that might be better. Not sure how you can get the actual prefix of the directory. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. The PATH modification always felt kinda sketchy.